# Can't acces method in startup from scoped service

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a basic interface and class that I've registered as a scoped service in the "ConfigureServices".

Example:

```
services.AddScoped<ICachingDataManager, CachingDataManager>();
```

In this class CachingDataManager I inject a DbContext from EF. This context is then registered in the "ConfigureServices". Nothing fancy.

```
services.AddDbContext<PhoneContext>();
```

Now I want to run a method from CachingDataManager on startup (it initializes the cache to give some context). So in the "Configure" part I run:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ICachingDataManager>().Initialize();
```

Here it keeps failing because it's a scoped service, if I execute a method from a singleton this executes without any problem.

Any insights?

Comment: So what did you expect? If it's a scoped service - you need to initialize it at the beginning of scope (for example in constructor), doesn't make much sense to initialize it once at startup?

Comment: @Evk When the application starts I want to initialize itself, the scoped service is then further used troughout the lifecycle of the application to update itself. But it has to initialize itself at startup

Comment: But how can it initialize itself once if there are many instances of this service? Or that is some kind of static initialization which is valid for all instances? But then it's strange to have it as instance method of that service.

Comment: @Evk The scoped service formats data and passes it to a singleton cache service

Comment: Then maybe move Initialize method to singleton caching service? Isn't that what you initialize after all?

Comment: @Evk I can't since I need the DbContext from EF and it registers itself as a scoped service. A singleton can't consume a scoped service, that's the reason I abstracted the data formatting service from the caching service

Comment: Aha, so that one-time startup initialization involves using dbcontext?

Comment: @Evk Yes the CachingDataManager in the example injects a DbContext, uses it to fetch some data and then format that data. When the data is formated it send the data to a singleton instance (a cache store).

Comment: Still not clear for me what `Initialize()` method does. I understand that CachingDataManager uses context, but does this specific method uses DbContext in any way?

Comment: @Evk The idea is that when the applications starts, it fetches data with EF and then saves that data in a cache. In order to use EF I need to register that context, which is a scoped service. I can't use any initialize method from my cache since it's a singleton and it can't consume the context from EF. So I created the CachingDataManager as a scoped service so that this could inject that context and use it to fetch data. When I have the data I send it over to the cache. I need the Initialize method to start loading data to the cache

Comment: Can't say I like the design, but I suppose you can wordaround with `using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()) {
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICachingDataManager>().Initialize();
            }`